# What is kth vortex formula?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fluid-dynamics

I want to study the kth vorticity equation. The NS equation is provided as

\begin{align}\label{eq1}
 &\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} \textbf{u} + \left(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{u} =    \nu \bigtriangleup \textbf{u} -\dfrac{1}{\rho}  \textbf{Grad}(p)
\end{align}

which implies

\begin{align}\label{eq2}
 &\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} \textbf{curl}^k(\textbf{u}) +  \textbf{curl}^k\biggl(\left(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{u}\biggr) =  \nu~ \bigtriangleup  \textbf{curl}^k( \textbf{u}) \tag{1}
\end{align}

with $$\textbf{curl}^k(\textbf{u}(x,t)) = \textbf{curl}(\textbf{curl}\cdots \cdots \textbf{curl})(\textbf{u}(x,t))$$ where we apply the curl $k$ times in succession. I want to compute $\textbf{curl}^k\biggl(\left(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{u}\biggr)$ for each $k$. We know for $k=1$ we have $$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} \textbf{v} + \biggl((\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla )\textbf{v} -(\textbf{v}\cdot \nabla )\textbf{u} \biggr) = \nu~\bigtriangleup \textbf{v} , ~~~~~ \textbf{v}= \textbf{curl}(\textbf{u}).$$ Is it true in general $$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} \textbf{v}^k + \biggl((\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla )\textbf{v}^k-(\textbf{v}^k\cdot \nabla )\textbf{u} \biggr) = \nu~\bigtriangleup \textbf{v}^k, ~~~ \textbf{v}^k:= \textbf{curl}^k(\textbf{u}(x,t))$$

Comment: your $k=1$ equation has the wrong sign for the two terms between $\bigl( \cdots \bigr)$;  see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4595461/87355 ; the generalization to larger $k$ will include more terms than just these two

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thank you sorry about that. I thought induction would work but maybe not if the terms don't cancel.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker if no terms cancel we should get 2 more terms from each term involved. So we have $2^k$ terms for each $k$. Or some of them cancel

Comment: what is general formula for $$\textbf{curl}\left(\left(\textbf{a}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{b} - \left(\textbf{b}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{a}\right) $$

Answer (score 2):

Use that the velocity field is incompressible, $\nabla\cdot u=0$, to rewrite
$$(u\cdot\nabla)u_j=\sum_{i} \nabla_i (u_iu_j).$$
You seek the curl of the curl of this expression, use that
$$[\operatorname{curl}\operatorname{curl}f]_j=\sum_{i}\bigl(\nabla_j\nabla_i f_i-\nabla_i\nabla_if_j\bigr).$$
Hence
$$[\operatorname{curl}\operatorname{curl} (u\cdot\nabla u)]_j=\sum_{i}\sum_k\nabla_i\nabla_k\bigl(\nabla_j(u_ku_i)-\nabla_i (u_ku_j)\bigr).$$

---

To check that the conjectured formula in the OP does not hold, consider the divergence-free velocity field $u=(x+y,x-y,xy)$. On the one hand, $\operatorname{curl}\operatorname{curl} u=0$, so the formula in the OP gives 0, but $\operatorname{curl}\operatorname{curl} (u\cdot\nabla)u=(0,0,-4)$ is nonzero.

Comment: Im not so used to that notation with subscript under $\nabla$. I aim to solve the kth curl of non-linear term.  The formula you propose is the second curl or the kth one?

Comment: $\nabla_i \equiv \partial/\partial x_i$; so, for example, $\sum_i \nabla_i u_i = \operatorname{div} u$; this is the formula for the curl of the curl (second curl).

Comment: So this is only the second curl? My observation here is if we push $k$ to be large then maybe the kth curl of non-linear term will slowly vanish. So that at large values we can approximate the kth curl by solution to heat equation.

Comment: I don't think so; try $u=\{e^{x+y},-e^{x+y},e^x+e^y\}$, the $2k$-th curl of the non-linear term is $\{0,0,(-5)^k e^{x+y}(e^x-e^y)\}$, so it does not vanish for large $k$.

Comment: hmmmm if it doesnt vanish what can we say about it?

Comment: for a field that vanishes as infinity just take $u=\{e^{-x-y},-e^{-x-y},e^{-x}+e^{-y}\}$; the $2k$-th curl is $\{0,0,(-5)^k e^{-2x-2y}(e^x-e^y)\}$, so it does not vanish for large $k$

Comment: it doesn't mean this particular $\textbf{u}$ doesn't.  Maybe we can show it doesnt vanish

Comment: if the kth curl does not vanish for the non-linear term then maybe it tells us something about it.

Comment: one constraint would be that it needs to be infinitely differentiable, but it is even stronger then that. The components cant be too similar if kth curl always exist.